# Exception read file after 'cp' and 'chmod'

Tags: android, xamarin.android

`fromFile` - file for sudo permission
`toFile` - file in application folder (application can read from this directory)

Copying a file, additionally I set the rules `666`

```
Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec(new string[] { "su", "-c", "cp", fromFile.AbsolutePath , toFile.AbsolutePath });
Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec(new string[] { "su", "-c", "chmod", "666", toFile.AbsolutePath });
using (FileInputStream fr = new FileInputStream(toFile))
{
  ...
}
```

I get an exception in `FileInputStream`:

> /dir1/dir2/file.blablabla: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

PS: After completing these steps, I'm looking permission for file `toFile`  at filemanager. They are 666.

PS2: If these actions are carried out with a file from a public directory, no errors!

PS3: Device root

PS4: my Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="byInterv.SilenceClient" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.5" android:installLocation="internalOnly">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_FRAME_BUFFER" />
    <application android:label="Android Silence" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/Icon"></application>
    <receiver android:name=".GCMBootReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</manifest>
```

PS5: 
If I look file permissin from su then 666, if look from application (Java.IO.File.Can***()) then all false... :((

Answer (score 0):

Did you give storage acces permisions in manifest,Otherwise give this

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

and if your working on android m you have to set permission in rum time.

Comment: already in my project android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE  android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: access is granted, otherwise the file will not be copied and the right not installed.

Comment: which android version your using ?

Comment: 6.0 (Phone Alcatel 5045d)

Comment: if your your working in 6.
Go to setiings->apps->yourappname->permisiions->storage
and make sure it's enabled.

Comment: if it works fine in public directory,Nothing is wrong with the code.Then You can try one more option change your app to system app.Please let me know it fixes the problem or not

Comment: If I look file permissin from su then 666, if look from application (Java.IO.File.Can***()) then all false... WHY??? :((

Comment: You are  using cp with su permission,so it will work.

Comment: How do I grant permission for the app?

Comment: you have to make it system application.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. permission rw-.
and how to do it?

Comment: CanRead is true, but I get an exception. I suspect you need to change the file's owner. How to get answer.

Comment: you can change ownership by using "su chown -R username:group directory"

Comment: tried, the user is changing, however, open the read still fails

Answer (score 0):

able to create a file with the extracted data problem file, the destination file can be read.

`unreadFile` - the problem file

`fullTempName` - unlock file

```
using (Java.Lang.Process p = Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec("su")) {
using (DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.OutputStream))
{
  os.WriteBytes("cat \"" + unreadFile + "\"\n");
  os.Flush();
  os.Close();
  using (DataInputStream ins = new DataInputStream(p.InputStream))
  {
    byte[] buff = new byte[4096];
    int count = ins.Read(buff, 0, 4096);
    using (System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(fullTempName))
    {
      while (count > 0)
      {
        fs.Write(buff, 0, count);
        count = ins.Read(buff, 0, 4096);
      }
      fs.Close();
    }
  }
}
```

If there are other methods, please tell. Thank you